# Save a list of values from a user to storage then display them in a list

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I am creating an app that will convert a user input then display it in a `TextView`. But what I need to do is display the last 5 conversions. So I'm trying to figure out a way to do so. Would the best way be to get the user's input then store the input into some type of this and position it? I'm new to this so I might be completely wrong, if so can someone please tell me another route to go about this. The code below is the code for getting the users input then converting it and adding it to the `TextView` but I need it to be stored so I can have the last 5 conversions displayed

```
if (copper1Pressed && copper2Pressed) {
    convertedCost.setText("Converted cost: " + convert);

    myList.add(editText.getText().toString());
    myList.add(convertedCost.getText().toString());
    editText.setText("");
    String string1 = "Copper";
    String string2 = "Copper";
    for(String edit : myList) {
        edit = (string1 + " " + myList.get(0) + " = " + string2 + " " + myList.get(1));
        txtList.setText(edit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tayla. The simplest way to store and retrieve the data for a learning project is to use "SharedPreferences". If you have the ambition to a develop a full chat app then you might consider "Room" which is a simplification of a MySQL DB. Lastly, Firebase Realtime Database if you want the data hosted in Google's cloud.

Comment: Regarding the views that you are creating. I like the ambition in your solution. But you can run into problems creating a variable number of views in code because in some cases we end up creating more views than can fit on the screen and it becomes both slow and memory inefficient. A RecyclerView on the other hand, will show the last 5, 10, or 15 messages in a TextView, but will restrict the TextView creation to the number of TextViews that can fit on the screen. In Studio, "New -> Fragment -> Fragment List", It will create a RecyclerView list for you populated with sample data.

Comment: Thank you so much @Elletlar I have been playing around with using "SharedPrefrences" But all of the tutorials are showing how to store a text from the editText but I want to store the data that is in my txtList. How would I go about this?

Comment: No problem. Did you manage to get it working? I added some sample code below in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SharedPreferences does not provide an easy way to store an ordered list. A 'standard' Android developer trick is to use a JSON array instead:

To Save:

```
final JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("string1");
array.put("string2");
final String jsonString = array.toString();
sharedPreferences.edit().put("data", jsonString).apply();
```

The value of jsonString stored in SharedPreferences is:

```
(string1,string2)
```

To Retrieve:

```
final String stringData = sharedPreferences.getString("data");
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringData);
final String string1 = jsonArray.getString(0);
final String string2 = jsonArray.getString(1);
```

I'm assuming myList is of type `List<String>`, it should be possible to convert it directly into a JSONArray using the following constructor:

```
JSONArray(Collection copyFrom)
```

Sorry I am not in front of my computer or I would try it myself...

This is a simple example, but you could also store an array of `JSONObject` strings for example if you decide to associate another piece of data with your chat message, perhaps the timestamp.

But for a real commercial product, you should generally use a DB rather than storing JSONObjects as strings in SharedPreferences since you will probably want to run efficient queries on the data.